# Actualizar Estado cuando finalice un Job - PLSQL Oracle

Tags: stored-procedure, oracle-11g, plsql

Amigos:

tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, necesito guardar como un bitácora de control cuando se ejecute este procedimiento dentro de un job, que debe hacer lo siguiente inserta registro cuando el job esta en ejecución cuando finalice el job debe tener una hora fin y cambiar el campo estado a finalizado, por ahora no me actualizar el estado cuando defino una variable `v_max`

```
PROCEDURE SP_REGISTRA_BITACORA
    IS
    V_FECHA_AHORA DATE;    
    V_CANTIDAD NUMBER:=0;
    V_MAX NUMBER;
    V_ESTADO VARCHAR2(100):='EJECUCION';    
    BEGIN

     V_FECHA_AHORA := SYSDATE;
      SELECT COUNT(1)
        INTO V_CANTIDAD
        FROM STG.BITACORA_JOB;       
      SELECT MAX(CO_JOB)
        INTO V_MAX
        FROM STG.BITACORA_JOB; 
      IF V_CANTIDAD=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO STG.BITACORA_JOB(CO_JOB,DE_PACKAGE,FE_PROCESO,TX_HORA_INI,TX_HORA_FIN,ESTADO)
        VALUES (V_CANTIDAD+1,'DWHADM.PKG_SIGE_ADM_EGD',SYSDATE,SYSDATE,'',V_ESTADO);
      ELSIF V_MAX >= 1 THEN
        UPDATE STG.BITACORA_JOB
           SET TX_HORA_FIN   = V_FECHA_AHORA,
               ESTADO = 'FINALIZADO'[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
         WHERE TX_HORA_FIN IS NOT NULL;
      END IF;
      COMMIT;
      END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado

Al inicio de tu procedimiento asignas el sysdate a V_FECHA_HORA, estas asignado un valor a tu puntero y eso no cambia automáticamente pueden pasar 5 horas y tu V_FECHA_HORA será lo que asignaste al principio.

Si quieres la hora actualizada simplemente usa SYSDATE directamente y no uses tu variable V_FECHA_HORA (Me parece que está demás).

SET TX_HORA_FIN = SYSDATE